# Is there a way to better manage sql statements/queries in a program with multiple (hundreds) php files?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I use php to fetch data from a mysql database for a web application that I am working on.  I have over a hundred php files, each with a number of sql statements.  Currently I run the risk of forgetting to update queries in other files when a change is made.

Is there a way to better manage all these sql statements/queries?

I was thinking along the lines of having a file with a list of different functions each querying the database for the relative sql statement.  It can be the case that a particular statement is used in multiple files.  Instead of having to write out each statement in each file, I can just call the relevant function with the sql statement.  Then if I have to update the statement for any reason (i.e. additional fields added to the table, etc) then I can update the query in one place, I dont have to search through multiple files and make an update, and I dont have to worry about missing a file to update.

Im only not entirely sure of whether functions is the best way to go about this because of scope.  The config file has the db connection credentials, il have to think about how to pass variables to the function,... its a rabbit hole I dont want to go down yet unless I know im on the right track.

Looking forward to any help and advice as well as any examples or resources to assist

Many thanks.

Comment: MVC architecture with an ORM is a good way to do that

Comment: Congrats, you have discovered what we call [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). This is a good thing. It is impossible to elaborate further given the lack of detail, but you are going in the right direction.

Comment: At a very high level, centralizing your code (DB in this case) to a dedicated "thing" is usually a recommended practice. The "thing" can be file, class, or even a library, and that depends on your current code base and personal preferences. When I refactor, I usually first centralize, then I see if there's a pattern that I can apply to make function/method arguments easier. An IDE is a good investment here, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, what do you mean by centralize?  Im still not certain (haven't done the research yet based you the suggestions above) how to go about centralising code with regards to SQL statements.  Would you have a simple example to share?

Comment: A possible example. Make a class called `Database` and have methods such as `updateUser($id, $firstName, $lastName)` or `updateUserFirstName($id, $name)`. Repeat with each. These methods can be static, or if you could have a global instance. This just gets everything into one place. Eventually you might want to have a user-specific Database class, as well as a blog-specific one. But I like to centralize first, then optimize later when I refactor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.